# Poisson random variable problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

At time $t=0$, an infinite chess table has a turned on light bulb on each square (the length of a square side is 1).Every minute, approximately half of the remaining light bulbs are switched off. After $3$ minutes we draw a circle of radius $R=1000$ on the table. How many functioning light bulbs does the circle encompass (approximately) and what's the maximum error of this evaluation ?

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this ? I'm completely clueless.

Comment: First, find out how many bulbs are encompassed by the circle (not regarding their on/off state)

Comment: The maximum error happens when either all are switched off or all are left on.  The likely error is much smaller and might be estimated using a binomial distribution or an approximation to it.

Comment: There are 3141549 light blubs at a distance $\le 1000$ from the center (ref [OEIS A000328](http://oeis.org/A000328)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described, each bulb's on/off status is a Poisson random variable with mean and variance $1/8$.  Since there are approximately $\pi r^2 \approx 3141593$ bulbs in a circle of radius $1000$, the expected number of "on" bulbs is $\pi r^2/8\approx 392699$, and the standard deviation is the square root of this, or about $627$.  In round figures, the number of "on" bulbs is $392700 \pm 600$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! If you don't mind, could you recommend a reliable source on those Poisson random variables? I couldn't follow most of your proof and I didn't understand how the elapsed 3 minutes influenced your computations..

Comment: @Victor $1/8 = (1/2)^{3\text{min}/1\text{min}}$

Comment: @achillehui oh, thanks, didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

When you say half the lights are turned off do you mean in terms of finite densities? To be specific let $d(t,x)$ be the number of lights on at time $t$ in a circle (or pick any shape you want) of radius $x$ around the origin. Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} d(t+1,x)/d(t,x)=1/2$.

If this is the case there's no right answer. Imagine at each time turning off every second column of lights. This gives you a halving scheme but what happens in a circle of radius $R$ heavily depends on the scheme. Are you randomly picking the origin of the circle? If it's around the origin (say), then you could not touch the 1000 columns to left/right of the origin and still get the above halving scheme, giving you a circle of all lights turned on.

Comment: Well, the problem provides no other details so I can't say I know anything else about the circle other than what I hypothesised..

Comment: What is the problem source?

Comment: I don't have the source, our calculus professor posted it on our facebook group.